# How to use Bonjour Software Development Kit to search for devices in local network

Tags: c#, .net, bonjour

Apple provides Bonjour Software Development Kit(SDK) for Windows: https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/ . But I cannot find any **tutorials** or **snippets** or **examples** so I do not know even where to start.

I work in my local network: addresses from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.0.255`. I have few ip cameras connected to this network.

**Problem:** I am looking for snippet allowing me to only discover their IP(cameras) addresses in that network(I do not need connect to them or anything else - I've already solved connection problem when I know the ip address).

Is anybody expierienced enough with Bonjour to know how discover ip cameras addresses?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with [Mono.Zeroconf](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf) as it'll bind to Bonjour on Windows.

Comment: Ok but can it scan ip range to discover ip camera?

Comment: If the camera publishes its information through Bonjour, then certainly. But it doesn't "scan". Bonjour is all about the server publishing its information (ports, ip addresses, etc) which then the client can discover and connect. To see what information is published on your network use the Bonjour Browser http://hobbyistsoftware.com/bonjourBrowser

Comment: Could you glance at my question please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065459/what-is-the-hostname-while-invoking-getaddrinfo-in-bonjour-1-0-net-c