# How to get an IP address in local network and its http port having MAC of the device

Tags: c#, .net, ip

I have a MAC of the device connected to my local network: 00408CBEEAE5.

**How query for that device's IP address in C#?**

Comment: Seems like two different questions. First isn't hard, second just needs a port scanner.

Comment: You could mine the output of ARP.exe for the ip. Http port. Well there could be several. Look up Port Scanning. NB if the machines have software firewalls or they are behind switches, you might set of a pile of intrusion attempts and other security warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a method [GetIpNetTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  from `IpHlpApi.dll`.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/358946/Retrieving-IP-and-MAC-addresses-for-a-LAN) you can find sample code how to use this method from .Net and PInvoke. It will return `Dictionary<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress>`, but you can update it to return just one `IPAddress` based on `PhysicalAddress`.

About second one question, yes, you need to iterate all opened ports on that host, and check if any of them returns correct Http response, that means that WebServer listening this port. But it won't be so fast. And some firewalls like `Outpost Firewall` can think that it's an attack and block your IP for some time.

**UPDATE1**

Copied code from sample

```
public class IPHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MIB_IPNETROW structure returned by GetIpNetTable
    /// DO NOT MODIFY THIS STRUCTURE.
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MIB_IPNETROW
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwIndex;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwPhysAddrLen;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte mac0;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte mac1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte mac2;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte mac3;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte mac4;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte mac5;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte mac6;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte mac7;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwAddr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// GetIpNetTable external method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pIpNetTable"></param>
    /// <param name="pdwSize"></param>
    /// <param name="bOrder"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("IpHlpApi.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    static extern int GetIpNetTable(IntPtr pIpNetTable,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref int pdwSize, bool bOrder);

    /// <summary>
    /// Error codes GetIpNetTable returns that we recognise
    /// </summary>
    const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the IP and MAC addresses of all known devices on the LAN
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 1) This table is not updated often - it can take some human-scale time 
    ///    to notice that a device has dropped off the network, or a new device
    ///    has connected.
    /// 2) This discards non-local devices if they are found - these are multicast
    ///    and can be discarded by IP address range.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Dictionary<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress> GetAllDevicesOnLAN()
    {
        Dictionary<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress> all = new Dictionary<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress>();
        // Add this PC to the list...
        all.Add(GetIPAddress(), GetMacAddress());
        int spaceForNetTable = 0;
        // Get the space needed
        // We do that by requesting the table, but not giving any space at all.
        // The return value will tell us how much we actually need.
        GetIpNetTable(IntPtr.Zero, ref spaceForNetTable, false);
        // Allocate the space
        // We use a try-finally block to ensure release.
        IntPtr rawTable = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            rawTable = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(spaceForNetTable);
            // Get the actual data
            int errorCode = GetIpNetTable(rawTable, ref spaceForNetTable, false);
            if (errorCode != 0)
            {
                // Failed for some reason - can do no more here.
                throw new Exception(string.Format(
                  "Unable to retrieve network table. Error code {0}", errorCode));
            }
            // Get the rows count
            int rowsCount = Marshal.ReadInt32(rawTable);
            IntPtr currentBuffer = new IntPtr(rawTable.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Int32)));
            // Convert the raw table to individual entries
            MIB_IPNETROW[] rows = new MIB_IPNETROW[rowsCount];
            for (int index = 0; index < rowsCount; index++)
            {
                rows[index] = (MIB_IPNETROW)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(currentBuffer.ToInt64() +
                                            (index * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIB_IPNETROW)))
                                           ),
                                            typeof(MIB_IPNETROW));
            }
            // Define the dummy entries list (we can discard these)
            PhysicalAddress virtualMAC = new PhysicalAddress(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
            PhysicalAddress broadcastMAC = new PhysicalAddress(new byte[] { 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255 });
            foreach (MIB_IPNETROW row in rows)
            {
                IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(BitConverter.GetBytes(row.dwAddr));
                byte[] rawMAC = new byte[] { row.mac0, row.mac1, row.mac2, row.mac3, row.mac4, row.mac5 };
                PhysicalAddress pa = new PhysicalAddress(rawMAC);
                if (!pa.Equals(virtualMAC) && !pa.Equals(broadcastMAC) && !IsMulticast(ip))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("IP: {0}\t\tMAC: {1}", ip.ToString(), pa.ToString());
                    if (!all.ContainsKey(ip))
                    {
                        all.Add(ip, pa);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Release the memory.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(rawTable);
        }
        return all;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the IP address of the current PC
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IPAddress GetIPAddress()
    {
        String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
        foreach (IPAddress ip in addr)
        {
            if (!ip.IsIPv6LinkLocal)
            {
                return (ip);
            }
        }
        return addr.Length > 0 ? addr[0] : null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the MAC address of the current PC.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static PhysicalAddress GetMacAddress()
    {
        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            // Only consider Ethernet network interfaces
            if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet &&
                nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                return nic.GetPhysicalAddress();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the specified IP address is a multicast address
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ip"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsMulticast(IPAddress ip)
    {
        bool result = true;
        if (!ip.IsIPv6Multicast)
        {
            byte highIP = ip.GetAddressBytes()[0];
            if (highIP < 224 || highIP > 239)
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    } 

    public static IPAddress GetIPAddress(PhysicalAddress physicalAddress)
    {
        var localIPs = GetAllDevicesOnLAN();
        foreach (var pair in localIPs)
        {
            if (pair.Value.Equals(physicalAddress))
                return pair.Key;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {// Get my PC IP address
        Console.WriteLine("My IP : {0}", IPHelper.GetIPAddress());
        // Get My PC MAC address
        Console.WriteLine("My MAC: {0}", IPHelper.GetMacAddress());
        // Get all devices on network
        Dictionary<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress> all = IPHelper.GetAllDevicesOnLAN();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<IPAddress, PhysicalAddress> kvp in all)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IP : {0}\n MAC {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }

        PhysicalAddress ph = PhysicalAddress.Parse("485B39C25E67");

        var ip = IPHelper.GetIPAddress(ph);
        Console.WriteLine("IP is {0}", ip);

    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code in section: "The code that does the work" does not compile at all.

Comment: It just says expected class, enum, interface or struct in many places.

Comment: yes, because that section misses `class` definition, so you need to add it. I've added complete sample into answer

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling with it.  Because I can only get MAC(of desired device) using method (below -> bonjour, but I cannot get ip address from bonjour) and then ip using your method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065459/what-is-the-hostname-while-invoking-getaddrinfo-in-bonjour-1-0-net-c